# How to declare typescript class field by using index signature

Tags: typescript

```
type TField = {
  field1: string;
  field2: boolean;
  field3: TMyCustom;
}

class Test1 {
  // I want to declare class field with this index signature
  [key: keyof TField]: TField[typeof key]

  // I don't want write field one by one
  // field1: string;
  // field2: boolean;
  // field3: TMyCustom;

  constructor() {
    // But TS Can't infer from index signature
    // Error : Property 'field1' does not exist on type 'Test1'
    this.field1 = 'initialField1'
    // Error : Property 'field2' does not exist on type 'Test1'
    this.field2 = true;
    // Error : Property 'field3' does not exist on type 'Test1'
    this.field3 = '';
  }
}
```

I want to declare class field by using typescript's index signature.

In the above example, I declare class Test1 next to the TField, to simplify my situation.

But in my project code, I should import TField from lots of file. So I can't declare field of Test1 one by one.

I'm not sure whether I was wrong to write ts index signature or ts did not support this kind of type.

-----------  question addded

```
type TField = {
  field1: string;
  field2: boolean;
  field3: TMyCustom;
}

class Test0 {
  // Previously, I declare "fields" property type of TField
  fields: TField

  // But now, I want to declare and access field1,2,3 at the class property level,
  // not inside of the "fields" property.

  constructor() {
    this.fields = {
      field1: 'initial field1',
      field2: true,
      field3: {some: 'object'} as TMyCustom,
    }
  }
}
```

Before I tried to convert to index signature, my code looks like the Test0 class.

I know you have a curiosity about "why you declare "fields" property and nested the field1,2,3 inside of that, not just declare field1,2,3 as the class property?". But this is related to the project structure. So put it aside, please.

Because of the field1,2,3 are contained in the fields property, I should assess the field1,2,3 like this `test0Instance.fields.field1`

So I wrote this question whether I can use the index signature to declare class field or not.

Comment: *"So I can't declare field of Test1 one by one."* But you assign them in the constructor one-by-one - if you can't know that the fields won't change and you don't want to duplicate their declarations within the class, then how are the fields going to be initialised?

Comment: I agree with @kaya3 that it would be nice to see a more motivating example; something where the constructor implementation doesn't need to mention each property individually would help a lot.

Comment: @kaya3 That's why I want to declare class field by using index signature. ` [key: keyof TField]: TField[typeof key]` 
Maybe I got confused on the usage of index signature...

Comment: But that declaration doesn't initialise the fields. In the constructor you are writing `this.field1 = 'initialField1'` which means the constructor knows that there is a field named `field1` of type `string`. So why can't the rest of the class know that?

Comment: @casamia the question is one of motivation; if you are going to *initialize* the fields individually, then you might as well do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2KvbN) for the same amount of effort.  If you had a different use case, such as a class constructor that takes a parameter of type `TField` and produces an instance which extends `TField`, then I could imagine wanting this, and maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBPBzW) would be the solution.

Comment: @kaya3 I've editted questions. Check please. I'm thinking about your advise...

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your example. It's interesting. But not suitable in my case. and.. Oh yes, I receive parameter of type TField from constructor.

Comment: You pretty much have to declare the fields one by one.  Index signatures will not work here, as the keys would need to be `string` or `number` (or soon `symbol` or placeholder string literals); you'd need a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) instead, but mapped types are not accepted in interfaces or classes.  And you can't simply not declare the fields, as per [microsoft/TypeScript#766](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/766).  If one of the other solutions I posted looks good to you, I'll write up an answer. Let me know.

Comment: Wait, you receive a parameter of type `TField` from the constructor, but [this solution](https://tsplay.dev/mpDQgm) with `Wrapper` doesn't work for you?  Please say *why* it's not suitable instead of just saying it's not suitable.  I mean, unless you'd like an answer saying "no you can't do this", which is possible but not that interesting.

Comment: @jcalz Oh wait, I should have look more carefully The wrapper and holder solution. I thinks this technique can resolve almost of my problems...

Comment: @jcalz Wow...... how did you come up the idea of wrapper and holder style. wow.... you are fxxking genious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) will not do what you want.  An index signature can let you declare that a `class` or `interface` acts like a dictionary with arbitrary `string` keys, or like an array with arbitrary `number`(-like) keys, and [starting in TypeScript 4.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#symbol-template-signatures), you can use arbitrary `symbol` keys or even ["pattern" template literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#template-string-type-improvements) like `` `hello-${string}` ``.  But you can't give a finite set of string literal keys like `keyof TField`. Even if you *could* do that, the compiler wouldn't let you map over each key individually; all the keys would have the same value type.  This is not what you want.

What you seem to want is to say that the `class` has keys of a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), of the form `[K in keyof TField]: TField[K]`.  But mapped types are not allowed to be part of `interface`s or `class`es.  They are standalone types.

There's no built-in solution for what you want.  In an alternate universe, TypeScript might have let you do this:

```
class AlternateUniverseTest implements TField {  
  constructor(tfield: TField) {
    this.field1 = tfield.field1;
    this.field2 = tfield.field2;
    this.field3 = tfield.field3;
  }
}
```

and either `implements TField` or the assignments `this.field1 = ...` would let the compiler know that `AlternateUniverseTest` has the same fields as `TField`.  But unfortunately `implements TField` does nothing to alter how the compiler infers what properties exist or their types (see [microsoft/TypeScript#32082](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32082) and many many linked issues); and the compiler will not allow you to leave out the property declaration in any case (see [microsoft/TypeScript#766](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/766)).

That means, in this universe, with this version of TypeScript, you need to declare individual properties inside your class body individually.  Or you need to work around it.

---

One workaround is to make a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) class factory helper function. You specify it an object type `T`, and it returns a class constructor of the form `{ new (init: T): T}` (that's a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures)):

```
function Wrapper<T extends object>(): new (init: T) => T {
  return class {
    constructor(init: T) {
      Object.assign(this, init);
    }
  } as any;
}
```

Note that the `class` expression inside the implementation is not seen to have any properties at all.  We know at runtime it will have whatever properties were in `init`, because that's what [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) does when you pass `this` as the first parameter.  But the compiler can't see it.  That's okay with us, we can use the `as any` [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler not to worry about it.  We mostly care about what happens when you *call* `Wrapper()`:

```
class Test extends Wrapper<TField>() {
  otherProp: number;
  constructor(tfield: TField) {
    super(tfield)
    this.field1 // <-- this exists now, no error
    this.otherProp = 100;
  }
}
```

By making `Test` a subclass of `Wrapper<TField>()`, we have a class body which already knows about `field1`, `field2`, and `field3`, and what their types are.  We have to call `super` and pass it a valid `TField`, which in this case we are getting from the construct call (but you could hardcode it if you want to).  You can add other properties the normal way too.

Let's just make sure this works:

```
const test = new Test({
  field1: "hello",
  field2: true,
  field3: ""
})

console.log(test.field1.toUpperCase()) // HELLO
console.log(test.otherProp.toFixed(2)) // 100.00
```

Looks good.  The compiler is happy and hopefully so are you.  It's a workaround, so there are probably caveats.  For example, if you don't want `Test` to be a subclass of anything (or if it needs to be a subclass of something else) then you will need to forget this approach, or at least modify it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=21&pln=7&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgsiAwgVwM7APYFsoF4roBOAlgHYDmA3ALABQdoksAYsRADYAmeUA3nVCgAzNlwCMALgLASFGrUEiOnAExSARhgzsIAQ1LzFozgGYp8JGkxZ5AXzp0A9ACooAOQyQ6AY3a7UqFAAguzAEISkumEAqqTEAG7hqBAwEOhQxFhgOlgQpMCBMKzKfIICUN4YpETI3piEABTASlzmxVwAlHzlgsAAFsSoAHQtnGI8zcYjxmKGglD9g9PKKhOjy1wqc70Dw6Mma1P7c-a0p86ODrS+-oVpwFAQAB5hpJyBAOqEumCQhAA8RWMAD4Gl1+AooBh+uEAAqETxSUjILDqcJzSrVGS1epNUZtYzgnoEZB-PGE4mLPYzKCORxQf4AWkZC12jyegwKUFIGAA7gAabkYR6EBGESm7IbQvpwhFgHhiAAMipOdFOPiq6TC6XwpAgvNg9waEKMykkUAARDL2OwMBb+eVRmoFoRkBAHZD9lILRa1R0rpjUNoIENbeQmvcNmMhphor9woh-BAwV06VAABIAUQAMtmAPIa6rB0MYcPa4BSmGEeGeGMYVhPCCcBoqDqp+lKxVDZVXXu0ITIUh1YhVKBfH5-QHs17vKHqABWEDqoI6SP1UAaZGIwHMXVwwNg3UhhAgwGQEQqfgCR-mFU12LqGEaW53sCJkNveYXS4rt2I5FIJpdkFF8Om2KBTkEWwoH8GDSBAOw+yQ+gUOQtDUIwq4gA)

Comment: This guy is type genius. If you, stranger, are helped by this answer, admire him. Really thanks @jcalz